# What is the practical purpose of -c in the linux install (/usr/bin/install) command?

Tags: installation

What is the practical purpose of -c in the linux install command? The man page shows:

```
-c     (ignored)
```

I came across this scenario while installing Nagios command-mode:

```
/usr/bin/install -c -m 775 -o nagios -g nagios -d /usr/local/nagios/var/rw
```

Answer (score 1):

From the `install` man page:

```
-c      Copy the file.  This is actually the default.  The -c option is only included for backwards compatibility.
```

I think it exhibits the same behavior for copying files and creating directories. Also, taking a look at https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/nagioscore/blob/master/Makefile.in#L37-L39 and https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/nagioscore/blob/master/Makefile.in#L415-L421 we can see that these are set by the `./configure` script.

Taking a look at `configure.ac` we see that it is the default autoconf macros that determine the binary to use: https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/nagioscore/blob/master/configure.ac#L17-L19. And it is Nagios specific for setting the `$(COMMAND_OPTS)`: https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/nagioscore/blob/master/configure.ac#L237-L240.

Hope this helps!

TL;DR: It's a relic and doesn't matter :)

Comment: Long time ago, but what's the source of the install man page entry above? All the sources I've been able to find so far list "-c (ignored)"!

Answer (score 0):

Historically, BSD's `install` would not copy files unless specified with the `-c` option. GNU Coreutils's version of `install` copied files by default, and provided `-c` as a BSD-compatibility option that is ignored. The [GNU Coreutils manpage](https://web.archive.org/web/20191128202806/http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/install.1.html) simply says

> -c (ignored)

and doesn't provide context. This is the version of coreutils present on most Linux systems.

[FreeBSD's manpage](https://web.archive.org/web/20190922111844/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.freebsd.org%2Fcgi%2Fman.cgi%3Fquery%3Dinstall) is a little bit more descriptive:

> -c    Copy the file.  This is actually the default. The -c option is only included for backwards compatibility.

Nowadays, there's no particular reason to use the `-c` option unless you want compatibility with very old systems. That being said there's also no particular downside to leaving it in since it's unlikely you'll be hitting the character limit for the command line, so it's kind of an "up to you" sort of thing.